# flask-wtf validate_on_submit() returns always true

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-wtforms

I am new to the flask-wtf. I did according to the documentation, but validate_on_submit() returns always true without validating as per the rules. Do I missing something or did something wrong?

Form:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, TextAreaField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Optional


class TemplateCreateForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField([Length(min=4, max=45), DataRequired()])
    view_path = StringField([Length(min=1, max=45), DataRequired()])
    caption = TextAreaField([Length(min=5, max=250), Optional()])
    is_active = BooleanField([DataRequired()])
```

controller.py

```
@submodule.route('/create', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@logged_user_only
def create():
    form = TemplateCreateForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        mongo.db.template.insert(
            {
                'title': str(form.title.data),
                'is_active': bool(form.is_active.data),
                'caption': str(form.caption.data),
                'view_path': str(form.view_path.data),
                'user_id': str(session['user.user_id']),
                'insert_timestamp': datetime.now()
            }
        )
    print form.errors
    return render_template('create.html', form=form)
```

view.html

```
<form action="{{%20url_for('template.create')%20}}" method="post">
    <h5 class="form-header">Template creation</h5>{{ form.hidden_tag() }} {{ form.csrf_token }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Title *</label> {{ form.title(class_='form-control') }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Caption </label> {{ form.caption(class_='form-control') }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">View *</label> {{ form.view_path(class_='form-control') }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="">{{ form.is_active(class_='form-check-input') }} Active</label>
    </div>{% for message in form.errors %} {{ message }} {% endfor %}
    <div class="form-buttons-w">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistakes in `class TemplateCreateForm`. Fields should be described in next format:

```
field = StringField('label_here', list_of_validators_here)
```

But in your case `list_of_validators` works as `label`. So, just add labels to all fields of Form.

```
title = StringField('title', [Length(min=4, max=45), DataRequired()])
view_path = StringField('view_path', [Length(min=1, max=45), DataRequired()])
...
```